Rigid body motion (RBM) transformation of interface points between a rigid and an elastic bodies



Above are pictures of a problem in mechanics. An elastic body occupying domain $\Omega$ is supported below with a fixed support and from above with a rigid body. The following calculations aim to express the movements of the points located at the interface $\Gamma_F$ between the rigid and elastic bodies in terms of a reference point $B$:
I don't understand them well, so I will explain my understanding (not sure it's correct), and confusion.
$\vec{y}(x) = \vec{x} + \vec{u}(x)$
The new position $\vec{y}$ of a point is equal to its original position $\vec{x}$ plus its displacement $\vec{u}$.
Rigid body motion transformation:
$\vec{y}(\vec{x}) = \vec{y}^B + \mathcal{R}(\beta) (\vec{x} - \vec{x}^B)$, where $\vec{x} \in \Gamma_F$
where $\mathcal{R}$ is the rotation matrix as the rigid body rotates at an angle $\beta$.
$\mathcal{R} = \begin{bmatrix}
cos(\beta) & sin(\beta)\\
-sin(\beta) & cos(\beta)
\end{bmatrix}$
Linearization for small deformation:
$\vec{u}(x) - \vec{u}^B = \vec{y} - \vec{y}^B - (\vec{x} - \vec{x}^B)\\
= (\mathcal{R}(\beta) - I)(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^B)$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.
For linearization we take,
$\mathcal{R} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \beta\\
-\beta & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
$\Rightarrow \vec{u}(x)\mid_{\Gamma_F} = \vec{u}^B + (\mathcal{R}(\beta) - I)(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^B)$
I don't understand how the displacement of the points on the interface are parametrized by the displacement of a reference point that is also located on the interface undergoing transformation as well.
Isn't a reference point supposed to be fixed?

I'm not going to attempt to follow your reasoning, but can you work out the system that merely consists of two horizontally separated vertical springs compressed/extended by a rotating bar above them using the same approach?

@GregLocock, in this case what could be taken as the reference point?

I don't know, it's your method not mine.

So with your springs suggestion, no reference is taken, right?

No, as I said, I have made no attempt to understand your method. It looks like B is the end of the beam.

Your actual problem is very non linear, more of the compressed side will come into contact as the angle increases. I have suggested you look at a linear case, using the same approach, merely so that you can check it against the standard solution.

The displacements are assumed small and a linearization has been made, no? For small angles
